# MySQL - Search table that contains Foreign key id with foreign key value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making search engine inside my platform, and I want to search specific table called `business_services`, that table contains a foreign key from another table called `services`.

The ideas that every business provide some of these services but I only store service ids in `business_services` table.

how I can search `business_services` table for a service using only it's id while I'm searching with name

and if that's not possible, I can make another column inside `business_services` table to store service name but how I can update that name whenever service name changes

business

```
| id  | name_en | name_fr | status |
|-----|---------|---------|--------|
| 134 | name 1  | nom 1   | 1      |
| 432 | name 2  | nom 2   | 1      |
| 325 | name 3  | nom 3   | 2      |
```

services

```
| id | name_en   | name_fr   | status |
|----|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 5  | service 1 | service 1 | 1      |
| 9  | service 2 | service 2 | 1      |
| 4  | service 3 | service 3 | 1      |
```

business_services

```
| id | business_id | service_id | status |
|----|-------------|------------|--------|
| 1  | 134         | 5          | 1      |
| 2  | 432         | 9          | 1      |
| 3  | 325         | 4          | 1      |
```

Comment: It looks like you simply inner join your tables. What have you tried so far and what is not working?

Comment: "and if that's not possible, I can make another column inside business_services table to store service name but how I can update that name whenever service name changes" Don't repeat information from one table in another, unless it is absolutely necessary to do so! Sometimes there is no better solution, e.g. to speed up information retrieval. But not in such a trivial case.

Comment: What you want to do in your query is join the two tables over the service_id column.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used inner join but I never thought to search for name in services table and load business information depending on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for example for service fr name called service 1.

```
select
    bs.*, -- all columns from business_services
    
    -- columns from services table
    s.name_en,
    s.name_fr,
    s.status
from
    business_services bs inner join services s on bs.service_id=s.id
where 
    s.name_fr = 'service 1';
```

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of searching services table it self instead of business_services. Thanks that worked very well

Comment: Although it won't affect the resulting execution plan, you should logically write the query `from services a join...` since this is the table you are filtering rows from.

Comment: @Stu true, i just wrote such query because I thought that Sam want somehow to get data from business_services